# Calling finish() doesn't stop execution of code

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, let's call them A and B.

A is an activity that can be started from two places in the app. I want to be able to know if A was started from place 1 or 2, so in B I call A like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
i.putExtra("code", code);
startActivityForResult(i, code);
```

(`code` is an int with the value 1.)

In the onCreate method of A I do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        int code = extras.getInt("code");
        if(code == 1)
        {
            ClearReleasesCache(); // just a private method of A
            setResult(1, i);                
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    // do everything else as usual
    setContentView...
}
```

Now, the problem is this (I've noticed it in debugging):

When I launch A from B, I want A to **finish**, as the code indicates here. When I launch A from another activity that's not B, I want it to run as usual (and it does). But `finish()` and `return` do nothing here - I can see when debugging that after the return call, it jumps back into onCreate, it doesn't shut down the activity.

That is, `onActivityResult()` in B is never called.

What's wrong here?

Comment: The argument of @sandy in his answer makes sense. Maybe you should move the check to the onStart() method?

Comment: It is impossible for `return` to "do nothing here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(extras == null || extras.getInt("code") != 1) {
         // do everything else as usual
 } else
       finish();
```

cant you just switch the if condition?

EDIT: but are you sure the return statement does not worK?

Answer (score 1):

how can it be finished before creating.. it gets finished once the current execution is complete.. not all of sudden in the middle of something... and it makes sense too..

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a return, statement after finish().

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this `setResult(RESULT_OK, i);`, i had a similar problem when i pass a resultCode different to RESULT_OK, and in that case onActivityResult() was never called

Answer (score 0):

What you have look correct - Have you check your parent Activity to see if it might be relaunching the Activity with null extras?

You can also adjust the logic slightly for a fix:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if(extras != null && extras.getInt("code") == 1) {
    ClearReleasesCache(); // just a private method of A
    setResult(1, i);                
    finish();
    return;
} else {

    // do everything else as usual
    setContentView...
}
```

However if your logic from the Parent (calling) Actvity is incorrent you will more than likely get the same results.